# how to open vertical drop down menu items to left align

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to open drop down vertical menu items to left side, for now it's opening at right side, but i wanted that it should opened at left side,

how could i achieve this? , i wrote following things to get this done

Css :

```
#navContainer
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #7398ba;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
}

    #navContainer ul
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        #navContainer ul li
        {
            position: relative;
        }

            #navContainer ul li span
            {
                display: block;
            }

            #navContainer ul li a
            {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                display: block;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            #navContainer ul li span:hover
            {
                /*background: pink;*/
            }

            #navContainer ul li a:hover
            {
                background: black;
            }

        #navContainer ul ul
        {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
        }

            #navContainer ul ul li a
            {
                background: #bec8cb;
            }

        #navContainer ul li:hover ul
        {
            width: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            left: 218px;
            top: 0;
        }
```

HTML :-

```
<div id="navContainer">
        <ul>
            <li><span><a href="#">Home</a></span></li>
            <li>
                <span><a href="#">About </a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Our business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our History </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span><a href="#">Services</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web templates </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="#">Contact</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">News</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

current result :-

[image]

**a result that i wanted**

[image]

Comment: make jsfiddle of your code

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you this time, I figure it out by wrapper the `ul` element by a `div`, and use absolute position two times. so that I can achieve this result.

- first time left align the wrapper by `left: 0`
- second time left expanded the dropdown by `right: 0`

code example:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>Trigger Dropdown</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change `left` to `right` in your absoluting positioning. In your case:

Change:

```
#navContainer ul li:hover ul
    {
        width: 80%;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        left: 218px;
        top: 0;
    }
```

To:

```
#navContainer ul li:hover ul
    {
        width: 80%;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        right: 218px;
        top: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

or you can change the pixels of `#navContainer ul li:hover ul` from positive to  negative like this

`left: 218px` ==> `left: -218px` /whatever is the width of your dropdown ul/

Answer (score -1):

Change the `left:218px` to - value and give `margin-left` to main `navigation ul`

```
#navContainer
{
    margin: 0 0 0 218px;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #7398ba;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
}
     #navContainer ul li:hover ul
        {
            width: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            left: -178px;
            top: 0;
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3GEfb/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the `navContainer` to the right like:

```
#navContainer
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #7398ba;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
    float: right;
}
```

then use the `right` property instead of the `left` property on the `ul`

```
#navContainer ul li:hover ul
{
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 218px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#navContainer
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #7398ba;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}

#navContainer ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

}

#navContainer ul li
{
    position: relative;
}

#navContainer ul li span
{
    display: block;
}

#navContainer ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
}

#navContainer ul li span:hover
{
    /*background: pink;*/
}

#navContainer ul li a:hover
{
    background: black;
}

#navContainer ul ul
{
    position: relative;
    display: none;

}

#navContainer ul ul li a
{
    background: #bec8cb;
}

#navContainer ul li:hover ul
{
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 218px;
    top: 0;
    margin-left:-380px;
}



<div id="navContainer">
        <ul>
            <li><span><a href="#">Home</a></span></li>
            <li>
                <span><a href="#">About </a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Our business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our History </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span><a href="#">Services</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web templates </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="#">Contact</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">News</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```